# Reactivity in shopping cart vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I am creating a really simple shopping cart (not considering vuex for keeping it simple) which would allow users to add in a couple of services. One of the methods is `addToCart()`.

```
addToCart(service) {
            if (this.cart[service.id] !== undefined) {
                this.cart[service.id].quantity =
                    this.cart[service.id].quantity + 1;
            } else {
                this.cart[service.id] = {
                    name: service.name,
                    quantity: 1,
                    price: service.price
                };
            }
        }
```

We have a data object `cart` which gets updated whenever any service is added to the cart.

```
data: {
        cart: {}
    },
```

However, it appears I am missing something as it is not reactive. When I try to loop through the object, it doesn't happen unless I go back to the previous step. So just tying to understand if there is anything else I need to do.

```
<tr  v-for="item in cart">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this.$set(object, key, value)`.

Example,

```
this.$set(this.cart, service.id, {
    name: service.name,
    quantity: 1,
    price: service.price
})
```

Since the cart is empty at first, when you add property to `cart` object, vue isn't aware of the changes. So to notify vue we use `this.$set`. Another solution is to define all properties in advance.

More details: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects